# Python Panda Removing Full JSON from File and Dealing with Nonexistent Objects

Tags: python, pandas

I am brand new to Panda, and I recently got help on the first set of problems I was having and you guys really helped me fix that issue, but now I have another one that I didn't realize was possible in my data and I have no idea how to fix it.

What I need done is all JSON that have "severity_modification_type": "NONE" as a column should remove that entire thing, as all the data in there isn't required or needed, basically deleting the entire JSON.

The Next one is just more of a question of how do you deal with trying to pull something that may or may not be there? Such as if a JSON is missing something you are trying to call, like a CVE. Is there a way to have the program bypass that error or to put in "No CVE"

Below you will find an example of all the different things in the JSON file I am looking for, along with the code I have as it stands.

```
#Opens Asset File and Attempts to turn it into a flat table
file = open("assets.json",)
file_json = json.load(file)


for file in file_json: # "assets.json" contains an array of data
    data = pd.json_normalize(file) # here we load the json data into a DataFrame
    agent_hostname = data["asset.hostname"] # note the "assets"
    cve_number = data["plugin.cve"] #Attempts to find CVE Number
    
    print(agent_hostname,cve_number)
```

```
[
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "John Smith",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "computer1",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "CVE-777-7777"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "Credacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "redacted",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "ACCEPTED",
        "state": "open"
    }
],
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "Jan Thomas",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "computer1",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "CVE-999-9999"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "Credacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "redacted",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
],
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "Frank Castle",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "Computer2",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "Credacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "redacted",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
],
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "Jan Thomas",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "computer2",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "CVE-999-9999"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "redacted",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
]
]
```

I have looked through various StackOverFlow answers and the ones I found didn't appear to work and gave me various errors about get. I imagine Pandas has a way to deal with this and while looking through the documentation I found drop() but that didn't appear to be able to solve the issues I was having with this.

After completing the answer from Jason Baker, I realized that what I wanted was clear. I am interested in all of the CVEs that might be attached to that hostname, so right now it looks like this.

```
            hostname             cve
0         computer1  CVE-7777-7777
1     computer2  CVE-7777-7777
2     computer3  CVE-7777-7777
3        computer4  CVE-7777-7777
4     computer5  CVE-7777-7777
..               ...             ...
574     computer575  CVE-7777-7777
575  computer576  CVE-7777-7777
576      computer577  CVE-7777-7777
577   computer578  CVE-7777-7777
578     computer579  CVE-7777-7777

[579 rows x 2 columns]
```

I would like for it to look more like this as the output

```
            hostname             cve
0         computer1  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-888-8888
1     computer2  CVE-7777-7777
2     computer3  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-666-6666
3        computer4  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-555-5555, CVE-666-6666
4     computer5  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-444-4444
..               ...             ...
574     computer575  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-756-9642
575  computer576  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-756-9642, CVE-444-4444
576      computer577  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-999-9999
577   computer578  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-756-9842
578     computer579  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-777-7888
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a list comp and [json_normailize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)?

Code:

```
 df = (pd
      .concat(objs=[pd.json_normalize(data=x) for x in file_json])
      .query(expr="severity_modification_type.ne('NONE')") 
      .filter(items=["asset.hostname", "plugin.cve"])
      .dropna(how="any")
      .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
      .explode(column="cve")
      .groupby(by="hostname", as_index=False)
      .cve.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, x)))
      )
```

Output:

```
    hostname                         cve
0  computer1  CVE-777-7777, CVE-999-9999
1  computer2                CVE-999-9999
```

Comment: I added the output of the information I was looking for, and I removing .explode(column="plugin.cve") didn't seem to fix that issue.

Comment: can you update fake data to reflect different hostnames since they are all "redacted" there isnt a way to do a groupby

Comment: I have changed the json data as requested, and it is closer to what the data I will be using is.

Comment: Yes, (On your comment if do you want this) that is basically the only way to remove 'false positives' from this reporting. That is basically saying that we are aware of that JSON and we have accepted that as a thing.

Comment: This appears to work great for my purposes! I have other things I need to do with this data on the back end and multiple APIs to manage but that isn't your problem. Thank you for your help!